# How to plot real time graph using python for the signals received from RTL SDR?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, python, software-defined-radio

Using the below python code, I am able to plot a graph. Can anyone please tell   me how to modify this code to plot the graph continuously in real time?

```
from pylab import *
from rtlsdr import *    

sdr = RtlSdr()    

sdr.sample_rate = 2.4e6
sdr.center_freq = 93.5e6
sdr.gain = 50    
samples = sdr.read_samples(256*1024)
sdr.close()   

psd(samples.real, NFFT=1024, Fs=sdr.sample_rate/1e6, Fc=sdr.center_freq/1e6)
xlabel('Frequency (MHz)')
ylabel('Relative power (dB)')
show()
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use GnuRadio or similar tools?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...you are right, we can use GNU Radio but I would like to do it with python.

Comment: Yeah, but a large part of GNURadio is written in Python.

Comment: This is a python programming question not a signal processing question. I suggest you ask on the main stack overflow programming exchange.

Comment: Thanks PAK-9, I will post this in Main StackOverFlow